# How to pass value of paragraph to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a paragraph tag that is manipulated using jquery. I have a list of checkboxes which changes the value of the paragraph everytime a new checkbox is selected. I would like to know if it is possible to pass that value across to the controller.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slectOne').on('change', function () {
            $('.slectOne').not(this).prop('checked', false);

            let result = $('.result', $(this).closest('.tabcolumn-container'));
            result.html($(this).is(":checked") ? $(this).data("id") : '');

        });
    });

</script>
```

My checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="R @item.standard_400.00 (per day)" />
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="R @item.super_400.00 (per day)" />
```

My paragraph tag:

```
<p class="result">Please choose cover to continue</p>
```

Comment: Only if you have a form control for it (or you pass it via an ajax call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can... but you probably don't want to. Instead you would post the value of the checkboxes that influence the paragraph...

If you do need to, you can get it as:

```
$(".result").val();
```

and post either using AJAX, or by appending a `<input type='hidden'>` to a form and then posting it.

Comment: I actually saw this way as the easiest way out until I figure how to pass the "data-id" of the selected checkbox to the controller

Comment: $(".slectOne[checked]").attr("data-id")